# Shortest path in directed graph passing thru specific vertices

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a directed graph $G$, vertices $s$, $t$ and group of vertices $U$, suggest a algorithm returning true if exists shortest path $P$ from $s$ to $t$, such that $P$ contains all $U$ vertices.

The graph is unweighted, we have to find shortest path in distance.

I was thinking about using reduction and BFS, But honestly I have no clue how to define the reduction graph.

The algorithm should run in linear time - $O(E+V)$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the Traveling Salesperson Problem which is NP-complete.

Comment: There in fact exists a simple linear time algorithm -- otherwise this wouldn't be given as an exercise.

Comment: I know for sure that such algorithm exists, It was given as homework In the university.